# How to correlate rlike and regex_extract

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

STATEMENT:1

```
spark.sql("select case when length(pop)>0 then regexp_extract(pop, '^[^@]+', 0) else '' end as pop from input").show(false)
```

STATEMENT:2

```
spark.sql("select case when length(oik)>0 and pop rlike '^[0-9]*$' then pop else '' end as pop from input").show(false)
```

How to correlate the above two statement regexp_extract and rlike,

```
sample input:1234@gamil.com output: 1234

sample input:1234abc@gmail.com output: ''
```

How can I correlate the two statements which I have given in a `case when` statement in `spark-sql…`(To combine `rlike` and `regexp_extract`) in a `case` `when` statement and to match the specified input and output?

- First statement is for neglecting the characters after @
- Second statement is for "if any non-numeric characters are present then it should reject from the first statement output"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
List("1234@gamil.com","1234abc@gmail.com")
    .toDF("pop")
    .createOrReplaceTempView("input")

spark.sql(
    """
      |select
      |    case
      |       when length(pop)>0 and pop rlike '^[0-9]+[a-z-A-Z]+@.*'
      |         then ''
      |       else
      |          case
      |             when pop rlike '^[0-9]+@.*'
      |              then regexp_extract(pop, '^[^@]+', 0)
      |           end
      |    end as pop from input
      |""".stripMargin)
    .show()
/*
+----+
| pop|
+----+
|1234|
|    |
+----+*/
```

Comment: how can we run the statement without given triple quotes to the query....could you please help me on that...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
val pattern = """([0-9]+)@""".r


def parseId(id: String): String = 
 id match {
    case pattern(id) => id
    case _ => “"
  }

val results = spark.sql("select case when length(pop)>0 then regexp_extract(pop, '^[^@]+', 0) else '' end as pop from input").map(parseId(_)).show()
```

Comment: I think that might work, but my question is how to correlate the two statements which I have given in a case when statement in spark-sql...(To combine rlike and regexp_extract) in a case when statement and to match the specified input and output. @james

Comment: @Vikram have you tried the `.select` [function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/sql-programming-guide.html)?

Comment: No @james .. my query should run in such a format(case when statement)